# Scala type mismatch when passing this

Tags: scala, polymorphism, type-mismatch

I have a question I was not able to answer myself and honestly also don't know what to really call it.

let me give you my code:

```
class Collection[+A](sorting: SortableCollection, contains: A*) {

  var sorter: SortableCollection = new SwapSorter()

  def add[B >: A](item: B): Collection[B] = {
    new Collection(sorter, (contains :+ item): _*)
  }

  def sort() = { sorter.sort(this) } 

  def getContains(): Seq[A] = {
    contains
  }
}
```

---

```
trait SortableCollection {

  def sort[A](c: Collection[A]): Collection[A]

}
```

---

```
class SwapSorter extends SortableCollection {

  def sort[A](c: Collection[A]): Collection[A] = {
    def order(): Seq[A] = {
      val seqnew: Seq[A] = c.getContains()
      seqnew.reverse
    }

    new Collection[A](this, order(): _*)
  }  
}
```

When in eclipse I try to define those classes in the Scala interpreter it will tell me:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : SwapSorter
required: SortableCollection
          new Collection[A](this, order(): _*)
```

Even though `SwapSorter` is a subtype of `SortableCollection`.
Is this due to contravariance of arguments? How would I work around this because I cannot instantiate a new `SortableCollection` itself.

I have the same issue at `Collection[A]` with the sort method.

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Collection[A]
required: Collection[?]
```

Comment: This code compiles without errors: http://scastie.org/10994

Comment: This is weird, maybe it has something to do with the way I do it in the Scala IDE?

I basically mark my Collection class completely. Ctrl+x, then with my Sortable Collection and swapSorter I do the same.

Comment: It works for me in Scala REPL 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_55) when entering all the code in paste mode: Collection, SortableCollection and swapSorter were all defined with no exception or error.

Comment: Curious.
Well the good thing is that it's not syntactically wrong it seems, and that is what's important for me at the moment (exam soon). It works for me if I use the code given by Alexey but I wanted to avoid putting everything into a single object class. I'll try to make it work some other time, for now I am satisfied with that.

Comment: Just pasted it in my Scala IDE and it compiles...